# Mysql select users who are not busy between a specific time range

Tags: mysql, time, range

I have a users table and tasks table. Users can have assigned tasks. Each task takes specific range of time. In the tasks table I have a user_id foreign key, date_start (unix timestamp), and date_stop (unix timestamp).

Let's say I want to assign new task which takes place today between 2:30am to 4:00pm to a random user who is free within those hours (doesn't have any task assigned to him which would overlap the new task).

What would be the proper SQL query to retrieve such users?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, it is not an overlap. This question is simpler, cause we know that `date_start` and `date_stop` can be linearly ordered (or, at least, should be).

Comment: The answer in the linked question shows you, how to check if two ranges overlap. Now you just need a `NOT EXISTS` subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `date_start` is always before `date_stop`.

Basically I consider users  with tasks that will begin after 4:00pm or with tasks that finished before 2:30am.

The `limit 1` is, of course, responsible for only one user being taken from DB.

```
select * from (
  select * from users
  join tasks on users.user_id = tasks.user_id
  where unix_timestamp(str_to_date('Feb 02 2017 04:00pm', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p')) < from_unixtime(tasks.date_start)
  or
  unix_timestamp(str_to_date('Feb 02 2017 02:30am', '%M %d %Y %h:%i%p')) > from_unixtime(tasks.date_stop)
) limit 1
```

Comment: This will find a user with a non overlaping task. But the same user could have another task assigned, which is overlaping.

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.id
from users u
cross join tasks new_task
where new_task.id = :your_task_id
  and not exists (
    select *
    from tasks user_task
    where user_task.user_id = u.id
      and user_task.date_start < new_task.date_stop
      and user_task.date_stop  > new_task.date_start
)
limit 1
```